# get row count in pdo class - after fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my pdo class

```
<?php
class Database
{
    protected $dbh;
    protected $query;
    public $rows;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$dbname)
    {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;

        // Set options
        $options = array(
                            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->query = $this->dbh->query($query);
    }

    public function fetchAllQuery()
    {
       return $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCountQuery()//--------------------------------(1)
    {
        //for get all the rows when query execute
        $arr = $this->fetchAllQuery()
        $this->rows = count($arr);
    }


}

$database = new Database('localhost','root','','speed');
$area='aa';
$price=200;


$query  = $database->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_deliverygrid"); 
$result = $database->fetchAllQuery();///-------------------------------(2)
echo '<pre>',print_r($result),'</pre><br>';



echo 'row count query [['.count($result).']]<br>';
$database->rowCountQuery();//---------------calling (1)
echo '['.print_r($database->rows).']';
echo '<br>';
```

i want to get row count of a query

for that instead of using  rowCount() method i use fetch all the rows to variable as a array and then count the elements of that array
rowCountQuery method consist above functionality

but i cant get row count now??? method returns null output

but if i remove (2) i can get and echo the output from rowCountQuery method
corrrectly

i want to know how to get row count not removing (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
class Database
{
    protected $dbh;
    protected $query;
    public $rows;
    protected $count;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$dbname)
    {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;

        // Set options
        $options = array(
                            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                        );
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->query = $this->dbh->query($query);
    }

    public function fetchAllQuery()
    {
       $result = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $this->count = count($result);
       return $result;
    }

    public function rowCountQuery()//--------------------------------(1)
    {
        return $this->count;
    }


}

$database = new Database('localhost','root','','speed');
$area='aa';
$price=200;


$query  = $database->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_deliverygrid"); 
$result = $database->fetchAllQuery();///-------------------------------(2)
echo '<pre>',print_r($result),'</pre><br>';



echo 'row count query [['.count($result).']]<br>';
echo '['.print_r($database->rowCountQuery()).']';
echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are consecutively fetching a result set twice in the same script, which will result in a `null` result for the 2nd request. Since you already have the result set after (2), you can execute `count()` on `$result`.